# Python Infinite While Loop Not Consistent

Tags: python, excel, infinite-loop, mt4

The code I have wrote in Python for an infinite loop works fine the first time. However, it gives the following message upon the second run:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 27, in 
symbol = str(symbol)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Any ideas why I am not getting this message after second run?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import win32com.client as win32
from oandapyV20.contrib.requests import MarketOrderRequest
from oandapyV20.contrib.requests import TakeProfitDetails, StopLossDetails
import oandapyV20.endpoints.orders as orders
import oandapyV20
from oandapyV20 import API
import oandapyV20.endpoints.accounts as accounts
import oandapyV20.endpoints.pricing as pricing
import oandapyV20.endpoints.positions as positions
import easygui
import tkinter as tk
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    for wb in excel.Workbooks:
        if wb.Name == 'forex2.xlsx':
            wb.Save()

    wb = open_workbook('C:/Users/dell/Documents/forex2.xlsx')

    xl_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    marginrate = xl_sheet.cell(1, 2)
    symbol = xl_sheet.cell(1, 1)
    symbol = str(symbol)
    marginrate = str(marginrate)
    symbol = symbol.replace("text:", "")
    marginrate = 20
    symbol = symbol.replace("'", "")
    print("Symbol:", symbol)
    print("Margin Rate:", marginrate)

    access_token = "XXXX"
    accountID = "XXXX"
    client = API(access_token=access_token)

    r = accounts.AccountDetails(accountID)
    client.request(r)
    dict = r.response

    params = {"instruments": symbol}
    r2 = pricing.PricingInfo(accountID=accountID, params=params)
    rv2 = client.request(r2)
    a = list(rv2.items())[1][1][0]
    ask = float(a['closeoutAsk'])
    print("Starting Ask:", ask)

    a = list(dict.items())[0][1]
    marginUsed = float(list(a.items())[25][1])
    marginAvailable = float(list(a.items())[26][1])
    balance = float(list(a.items())[9][1])
    print("Margin Available:", marginAvailable)
    print("Balance:", balance)
    print("Margin Used + Margin Available:", balance)

    STOP_LOSS = .001
    TAKE_PROFIT = 100000
    units0 = round((marginrate * marginAvailable) / ask * .95)
    print("Order Units:", units0)

    mktOrder = MarketOrderRequest(
        instrument=symbol,
        units=units0,
        takeProfitOnFill=TakeProfitDetails(price=TAKE_PROFIT).data,
        stopLossOnFill=StopLossDetails(price=STOP_LOSS).data)

    r = orders.OrderCreate(accountID, data=mktOrder.data)

    try:
        rv = client.request(r)
    except oandapyV20.exceptions.V20Error as err:
        print("")
        print("UNITS_INVALID")
    else:
        print("")

    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

    for wb in excel.Workbooks:
        if wb.Name == 'forex2.xlsx':
            wb.Save()
    book = open_workbook('C:/Users/dell/Documents/forex2.xlsx')

    r = positions.PositionList(accountID=accountID)
    client.request(r)
    dict = r.response

    a = list(dict.items())[0][1]

    for i, element in enumerate(a):
        long = a[i]
        long2 = long['long']
        symbol = long['instrument']
        try:
            averagePrice = long2['averagePrice']
        except:
            pass
        else:
            window = tk.Tk()
            frame_a = tk.Frame()
            label_a = tk.Label(master=frame_a, text="Hello")
            label_a.pack()
            frame_a.pack()

            for sheet in book.sheets():
                for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
                    row = sheet.row(rowidx)
                    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                        if cell.value == symbol:
                            row = rowidx + 3
                            current_bid = sheet.cell(1, row)
                            current_bid = str(current_bid)
                            current_bid = float(current_bid.replace("number:", ""))
                            str = "Beginning Balance:", balance, "Current Bid:", current_bid, "Average Price:", averagePrice, "Current Profit:", round(
                                (current_bid - float(averagePrice)) * units0, 2)
                            print(str)

                            data = {"longUnits": "ALL"}

                            r = positions.PositionClose(accountID=accountID, instrument=symbol, data=data)
                            client.request(r)
```

Comment: Near the end of your code, you create a variable called `str` which shadows the `str()` type conversion function, so the second time through `str` is a tuple and can't be called. Rename your variable in this line: `str = "Beginning Balance:", balance, ...`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your using 
`str = "Beginning Balance:", balance, "Current Bid:", current_bid, "Average Price:", averagePrice, "Current Profit:", round((current_bid - float(averagePrice)) * units0, 2)` 
,which replaces the function str with the variable you are assigning here. try replacing the name of this variable and it should work fine.